# I am not able to connect to my hidden WiFi network. (Ubuntu 18.10)

Tags: wireless, 18.10

I know where to go and how to connect. 
But the thing is, it does not connect no matter how much I try. This is so disappointing

Comment: What is/are the error message(s)?

Comment: Can you unhide wifi for a while? Btw hidding doesnt improve security too much.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen: Error message: "Authentication failure".

Comment: @LeonidMew: I want to hide. And Ubuntu should connect like in a normal Windows/Android OS.